# Weird results in search from wikidata

Tags: api, wikidata, sparql

I ve this query, which i want to find every instance of human with name Jose (already a first name like John, very common) in wikidata spanish, and then I get only 10 results. I believe is the way of the subquery, like if I made the filter of my 50 previous results, but I can't move the conditions without breaking the query.

my query:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "josé" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "es" .
      ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
      ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true .
  }

  ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
   FILTER (?type = wd:Q5)
OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?fecha_de_nacimiento. }
    FILTER(?fecha_de_nacimiento > "1900-12-31T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
} ORDER BY ASC(?num)
```

and my edit, is similar in result:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "josé" .
      bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "es" .
      ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
      ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true .
      ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
   FILTER (?type = wd:Q5)
  }


OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P569 ?fecha_de_nacimiento. }
    FILTER(?fecha_de_nacimiento > "1900-12-31T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
} ORDER BY ASC(?num)
```

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the FILTER? Do you get more results?

Comment: @BarryCarter for sure, but not data that I want, because is people born before 1900. But so I think the first subquery search for people before, give me 50 and then I filter that results so I get weird results. I move the filter to the first one but still, weird results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...like if I made the filter of my 50 previous results...

`Wikibase:mwapi` [supports](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual/MWAPI#Supported_services) the `limit` parameter of the Entity Search service:

```
SELECT ?item ?label ?order WHERE {
  VALUES (?type ?name) {(wd:Q5 "Jose")}
  SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" ;
                      wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" ;
                      mwapi:language "es" ;
                      mwapi:search ?name ;
                      mwapi:limit "50" .
      ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .
      ?order wikibase:apiOrdinal true .
      ?label wikibase:apiOutput mwapi:label .
  }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type .
  ?item wdt:P569 ?date. 
  FILTER (?date > "1900-12-31T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime) 
} ORDER BY ASC(?order) LIMIT 10
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%3Forder%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Ftype%20%3Fname%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ5%20%22Jose%22%29%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Amwapi%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aapi%20%22EntitySearch%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Aendpoint%20%22www.wikidata.org%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Alanguage%20%22es%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Asearch%20%3Fname%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20mwapi%3Alimit%20%2250%22%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wikibase%3AapiOutputItem%20mwapi%3Aitem%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Forder%20wikibase%3AapiOrdinal%20true%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Flabel%20wikibase%3AapiOutput%20mwapi%3Alabel%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Ftype%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fdate.%20%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fdate%20%3E%20%221900-12-31T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%20%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3Forder%29%20LIMIT%2010)

As you can see, results are still weird (but try e. g. "José Mourinho" instead of "José").

Possibly you should add some filtering using `CONTAINS`.

If you want to search people by their given names, probably you should use the `wd:P735` property, however, there is no fast way to get most "popular" or "relevant" results.

Comment: Thanks for you good response! Actually I don't want the limit of 50, the weird think I can figure in this is that how can be only 10 josé if I can list at least 30 in memory of people in wikipedia with named jose?

Comment: thats is the thing i cant understand :( why is happening that and how to fix it

Comment: from my understand i need to filter the first one subquery from wikibase mwapi with q5 entity

Comment: My two cents: Wikidata contains a lot of people [whose given name is "josé"](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fname%20%3FnameLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fname%20wdt%3AP735%20wd%3AQ2190619%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Ces%22.%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%20limit%20100), but this request does not require that. It asks for people whose one of the aliases is simply "José".

Comment: How do you make it with CONTAINS?

Comment: @LeandroTupone, it seems that this is an issue of Entity Search service. AFAIK, Entity Search service uses Elasticsearch index. Probably you could create an issue somewhere in subsubtasks of https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T78157. As for triplestores, they are for things, not for strings.

Comment: @LeandroTupone, you are welcome :-). Possibly related: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T125500